using multiple environment in serenity bdd with gradle tool
Step failed
net.serenitybdd.core.environment.UndefinedEnvironmentVariableException: Environment 'env' property undefined for environment '[]'
at net.serenitybdd.core.environment.EnvironmentSpecificConfiguration.lambda$getProperty$7(EnvironmentSpecificConfiguration.java:141)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
at net.serenitybdd.core.environment.EnvironmentSpecificConfiguration.getProperty(EnvironmentSpecificConfiguration.java:137)
at com.essentracomponenet.serenity.util.PropertyHelper.getEnvironment(PropertyHelper.java:53)
at com.essentracomponenet.serenity.config.LaHook.preProdAuthHandler(LaHook.java:606)
serenity.conf file contains env under environments. error should not be present
